# Amazon Linux 2 - EC2 PostgreSQL

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, amazon-linux-2

I've the following:

- Amazon Linux 2
- Postgres 12 installed a user created

I'm using ssh to connect to my instance.

The issue is that it doesn't let me to connect to my postgres database. I've created a user using something like:

```
create user myuser with encrypted password 'strongpassword';
```

and postgres server is running ok, but when i try to connect to my db it throws:

```
$: psql -h localhost --port 5432 --password -U myuser -d mydb    

psql: error: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

I don't know why it doesn't recognize my user.

Thanks in advance

---

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You'll have to add your user to pg_hba.conf and specify the network cidr in your entry.

The entries follow this format:

**`TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD`**

**Here's an example for a local connection using md5 (you have to specify the loopback address as a /32):**

```
local   myuser        all             127.0.0.1/32         md5
```

**Here's an example allowing a connection on the same class A network (you can always expand or restrict the CIDR more appropriately depending on your needs for the hosts that will be accessing your postgres server):**

```
host    all             myuser       10.10.0.0/24          md5
```

**Then reload postgres:** **`systemctl reload postgresql`**

After that, you should then be able to log in.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't work. I've updated my question why an screenshot maybe i'm using the wrong address. I want to connect from my EC2 to my PostgreSQL that is installed in the same EC2. Thanks in advance

Comment: for your pg_hba.conf you can change your `host    all             all       127.0.0.1/32      ident` to `host    all             all       127.0.0.1/32      md5`

Comment: you can also do the same thing for your 3rd entry for ipv6 or comment it out if you arent going to be connecting via ipv6 (the one that has `:1/128`